# Breakout a row into multiple rows with a maximum column value in SQL

Tags: t-sql, group-by, count, grouping

Column [A] could be any value, but if it exceeds 55, it needs to be broken out so that no row has a column [A] value exceeding 55 and so that none of the value is lost.

How would one accomplish this goal in SQL?

After searching around for a while and trying different things myself, I am lost. I am primarily a C# developer and have never tried to do this level of logic in SQL.

```
select '01' as id, 65 as cnt into #temptbl 
insert into #temptbl values
 ('02',100),
 ('03',200),
 ('04',45)

insert into #temptbl
select id, cnt - 55 from #temptbl where cnt > 55

update #temptbl set cnt = 55 where cnt > 55

    select * from #temptbl order by id
    select id, sum(cnt) as newCnt from #temptbl group by id

drop table #temptbl
```

Let's say I have a row where the value of column [A] is 200.
The maximum value of column [A] should be 55.
I need to split out this row into 4 rows.
3 rows would have column [A] valued at 55 and the last row would have column [A] valued at 35.

Comment: is there any max limit of A column?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out:

```
    select '01' as id, 65 as cnt into #temptbl 
    insert into #temptbl values
    ('02',100),
    ('03',200),
    ('04',45)

    declare @temptbl2 TABLE (id  varchar(2), cnt  bigint)
    while Exists(select 1 from #temptbl where cnt > 55)
    BEGIN
        insert into @temptbl2 select id, 55 as cnt from #temptbl where cnt > 55
        update #temptbl set cnt = cnt - 55 where cnt > 55
        insert into #temptbl select * from @temptbl2
        delete from @temptbl2
    END
            select * from #temptbl order by id
            select id, sum(cnt) as newCnt from #temptbl group by id

    drop table #temptbl
```

Comment: this will work, but LOOPs are slow in SQL, so you'll have performance problems on big sets

Answer (score 0):

Version without using loop

```
DECLARE @limit INT = 55;

SELECT '01' AS id, 65 AS cnt INTO #temptbl;

INSERT INTO #temptbl VALUES ('02', 100), ('03', 200), ('04', 45);

INSERT INTO #temptbl
SELECT       dupl.id
           , dupl.cnt
  FROM       #temptbl                                      AS t
 CROSS APPLY (   SELECT id
                      , @limit AS cnt
                   FROM (   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY S.object_id) AS row_num
                              FROM sys.all_objects AS S) AS a
                  WHERE a.row_num <= (t.cnt - 1) / @limit) AS dupl
 WHERE       t.cnt > @limit;

UPDATE #temptbl SET cnt = cnt % @limit WHERE cnt > @limit;

SELECT * FROM #temptbl ORDER BY 1, 2;

DROP TABLE #temptbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a recursive [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) for this.

The example uses a table variable for demonstration purposes.

```
declare @VarTable table (code varchar(2) primary key, cnt int);

insert into @VarTable (code, cnt) values
('01', 65),
('02',100),
('03',200),
('04', 45);

declare @Limit int = 55;

WITH RecursiveCTE AS
(
   SELECT code, IIF(cnt > @Limit, @Limit, cnt) AS cnt, (cnt - @Limit) AS Remaining
   FROM @VarTable

   UNION ALL

   SELECT code, IIF(Remaining > @Limit, @Limit, Remaining), (Remaining - @Limit)
   FROM RecursiveCTE
   WHERE Remaining > 0
)
SELECT code AS id, cnt
FROM RecursiveCTE
ORDER BY id, cnt DESC;
```

**Result:**

```
id  cnt
--  ---
01  55
01  10
02  55
02  45
03  55
03  55
03  55
03  35
04  45
```